# How do I know if appcheck is implemented correctly?

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-app-check

I have implemented AppCheck in my application following the Firebase documentation.
One of the videos says that for iOS, you just need to install the SDK and the configuration will be automatic.
However when I go back to the written documentation of AppAttest I see some code to put for the initialization, as an example :

```
class YourSimpleAppCheckProviderFactory: NSObject, AppCheckProviderFactory {
  func createProvider(with app: FirebaseApp) -> AppCheckProvider? {
    return AppAttestProvider(app: app)
  }
}
```

(I would like to clarify that my metrics are correct and that when I test my application, the requests are indeed accompanied by a valid token).

Do I have to implement it, and if not, what is it for?

Thank you!

Comment: One can check the AppCheck status on the Firebase console.

Comment: I have already done this and my application is well registered, I also have the user metrics. I just want to know what this code is for in the app attest documentation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**tldr;** Integrating AppCheck into your app may require some code changes depending on what attestation providers you want used to generate AppCheck tokens.

> How do I know if appcheck is implemented correctly?

If you're able to see [request metrics](https://firebase.google.com/docs/app-check/ios/devicecheck-provider#metrics) in the Firebase console, AppCheck is implemented correctly and working.

> One of the videos says that for iOS, you just need to install the SDK and the configuration will be automatic.

The AppCheck SDK will use Apple's DeviceCheck as the attestation provider [by default](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-ios-sdk/blob/master/FirebaseAppCheck/Sources/Public/FirebaseAppCheck/FIRDeviceCheckProviderFactory.h#L29-L30) to generate tokens. So, in this way, the configuration is automatic.

> However when I go back to the written documentation of AppAttest I see some code to put for the initialization...

Apple's AppAttest is a different attestation provider and is not used by default. If you want AppCheck to generate tokens using AppAttest, you'll need to add code to configure AppCheck to do so.

> Do I have to implement it, and if not, what is it for?

It **depends** on your use case, I'll explain:

The AppCheck SDK uses `AppCheckProvider`s to generate app check tokens.

AppCheck gets these `AppCheckProvider` instances from `AppCheckProviderFactory`s. As mentioned earlier, AppCheck will use DeviceCheck by default so if no `AppCheckProviderFactory` is manually set, AppCheck will use the conveniently implemented `DeviceCheckProviderFactory`.

You can set AppCheck's `AppCheckProviderFactory` by using the `AppCheck.setAppCheckProviderFactory(_:)` API. If you choose to do so, it must be done *before* calling `FirebaseApp.configure()`. See below example from [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/app-check/ios/app-attest-provider#initialize):

```swift
let providerFactory = YourAppCheckProviderFactory()
AppCheck.setAppCheckProviderFactory(providerFactory)

FirebaseApp.configure()
```

So, to answer your question, whether or not you implement the `AppCheckProviderFactory` protocol depends on what `AppCheckProvider`s you want used to generate app check tokens.

If you want AppCheck to use any provider other than the `DeviceCheckProvider` or a combination of providers, then you'll need to implement the `AppCheckProviderFactory` protocol and set AppCheck to use the implemented factory.

> There are 4 types of `AppCheckProvider`s:
>
> 1. [`AppAttestProvider`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/app-check/ios/app-attest-provider)
> 2. [`DeviceCheckProvider`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/app-check/ios/devicecheck-provider)
> 3. [`AppCheckDebugProvider`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/app-check/ios/debug-provider)
> 4. [Custom providers that you create as a subclass of `AppCheckProvider`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/app-check/ios/custom-provider)

For instance, here's an example factory implementation where AppCheck will use the debug provider if in debug mode, AppAttest provider if the OS version supports AppAttest, or falls back to using the DeviceCheck provider if AppAttest is not supported.

```swift
class YourAppCheckProviderFactory: NSObject, AppCheckProviderFactory {
  func createProvider(with app: FirebaseApp) -> AppCheckProvider? {
    #if DEBUG
      return AppCheckDebugProvider(app: app)
    #endif


    if #available(iOS 14.0, *) {
      return AppAttestProvider(app: app)
    } else {
      return DeviceCheckProvider(app: app)
    }
  }
}
```

As you can see, a custom `AppCheckProviderFactory` allows you to finely control what provider AppCheck uses.

I hope this answered your questions!

Comment: Thank you very much! I understand better now.