# How does Firebase App Check using iOS DeviceCheck work?

Tags: ios, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-app-check

I recently decided to enable App Check on Firebase for an iOS app I have running for a small <300 user group. For iOS projects Firebase has two options for App Check DeviceCheck and App Attest. I was able to turn DeviceCheck on without problems by uploading my Auth Key from my Apple Developer account. Everything seems to work without problems but I am not understanding what exactly is happening under the hood as the Firebase documentation only explains how to set it up and I want to make sure it is working correctly.

Could someone explain to me how Device Check works in this scenario with Firebase and how it is different from iOS App Attest that Firebase also supports?

Firebase iOS App Check Documentation:

[Firebase App Check DeviceCheck Guide](https://firebase.google.com/docs/app-check/ios/devicecheck-provider)

[Firebase App Check App Attest Guide](https://firebase.google.com/docs/app-check/ios/app-attest-provider)

Answer (score 20, accepted):

> How does Firebase App Check using iOS DeviceCheck work?

In short, SDKs will ask the AppCheck SDK for a special AppCheck token when making a request. When App Check is configured to use DeviceCheck, it will generate the requested token with the help of the [DeviceCheck](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/devicecheck) framework. Note that DeviceCheck is a framework created by Apple.

> I am not understanding what exactly is happening under the hood ...

And here's a little more detail to help clarify things:

The AppCheck SDK uses `AppCheckProviders` to generate app check tokens. There are 4 types of `AppCheckProvider`s:

1. [`AppAttestProvider`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/app-check/ios/app-attest-provider)
2. [`DeviceCheckProvider`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/app-check/ios/devicecheck-provider)
3. [`AppCheckDebugProvider`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/app-check/ios/debug-provider)
4. [Custom providers that you create as a subclass of `AppCheckProvider`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/app-check/ios/custom-provider)

For certain Firebase SDKs that support AppCheck enforcement (e.g. Firestore), they will ask the AppCheck SDK for an AppCheck token when sending a request. The AppCheck SDK generates a token using one of the 4 `AppCheckProviders` listed above. You can customize which provider is used by using AppCheck's `AppCheck.setAppCheckProviderFactory(_:)` API. I wrote more about it's purpose in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70842734/9331576).

> ... I want to make sure it is working correctly

If you're able to see [request metrics](https://firebase.google.com/docs/app-check/ios/devicecheck-provider#metrics) in the Firebase console, AppCheck is implemented correctly and working. If you've enabled enforcement, you should start to see some enforced requests in the metrics graph.

> Could someone explain to me how Device Check works in this scenario with Firebase ...

So when the AppCheck SDK is using the `DeviceCheckProvider` (this provider is the default one!), the AppCheck SDK will be creating AppCheck tokens with the help of Apple's [DeviceCheck](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/devicecheck) framework.

> how it (Device Check) is different from iOS App Attest that Firebase also supports?

The answer here can be found in Apple's documentation for [DeviceCheck](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/devicecheck).

In short, the difference is in the two names.

Device Check is useful for verifying that requests *are originating from an **actual** device*. For example, let's say you have an iOS app and are using Firebase AppCheck with the `DeviceCheckProvider`. If you enable enforcement, only requests coming from actual devices should be successful. So if I try to hit your backend API by `curl`'ing a request from the command line, it should get rejected since there is no token to confirm the request is coming from an **actual device**. This protects the backend from such abuse.

App Attest is part of the Device Check framework and offers more advanced verification by *attesting that the request is coming from a [valid instance of your app](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/devicecheck/establishing_your_app_s_integrity)*. To understand why this is useful, consider your iOS app is configured to use Firebase AppCheck with the `DeviceCheckProvider`. Let's say a hacker recompiles your app onto an actual device. In this case, DeviceCheck's effectiveness diminishes as requests sent from this malicious copy are technically coming from an "actual device" so a valid token will be generated. App Attest's more advanced attestation can attest that the request is coming from a **valid** instance of your app. In this example, the hacker's copy would not be a valid instance.

At this point, you might be wondering why you would ever use DeviceCheck when you can use the more advanced App Attest and the reason is OS availability: App Attest is only available for iOS 14.0+.

I hope this answered your questions!

Comment: I'm still unclear about how exactly AppCheck uses DeviceCheck to create a token. Apple says to treat DeviceCheck tokens as single-use. AppCheck tokens have a lifetime between something like 1 hour and 7 days, so clearly they are different in some way. Also, since DeviceCheck tokens are generated locally, there doesn't seem to be a rate limit. Does AppCheck introduce its own rate limit by involving a server in any capacity? We have a high number of users, so we need to make sure whether we would exceed any potential limits.

Comment: Does DeviceCheck detect/protects against jailbroken devices?

Comment: You are the best. thanks for writing this up

Comment: Beautiful answer to the question and thank you for answering my question before I asked: why use DeviceCheck over the more advanced App Attest? OS availability